# Can these C codes be refactored this way?

Tags: c, indentation

Is

```
if (i == 1) {
   printf("a\n");
   printf("b\n");
}
```

the same as

```
if (i == 1)
    printf("a\n");
    printf("b\n");
```

Can the codes be refactored this way?

Comment: Does the same happen when you run both codes?

Comment: i'm sorry but i haven't run it. i'm actually a newbie. is the second "refactored" code semantically correct?

Comment: Advice for a newbie: Write test programs. Play around. Experiment. Nothing beats getting your hands dirty.

Comment: No. In c, whitespace has no bearing on the code. It's there simply for human readability. In fact your second example is bad practice, since it "looks" like both `printf` lines are part of the `if` body, but only the first one is. I prefer always to use curly braces to may my intentions clear, but if you do not, the indentation should. Looking at your 2nd snippet, I don't know if you meant to make both statements part of the body or not. It could be a bug, it could be correct.

Comment: @yano: White space has some bearing on the code in C. Some combinations of special characters have different meanings when they are separated with whitespace than when they are not, and `0xe - 4` evaluates to 10 while `0xe-4` reports (in Clang) an invalid suffix on an integer constant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for pointing that out, thought there might be some corner cases when I made such an absolute statement but I couldn't think of any. Don't think I've seen that before.

Comment: @JohnKugelman not to mention also reading the manual.

Answer (score 4):

No. Without curly braces, the `if` test only applies to one statement. C ignores indentation completely. The second is equivalent to:

```
if (i == 1) {
    printf("a\n");
}
printf("b\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

No, They are different

the second is the equivalent of

```
if (i == 1) {
    printf("a\n");
}
printf("b\n");
```